# How to create an inline horizontal navigation with mixed text and icon links that's easy to adjust, tweak and improve?

Tags: website-design, icon, css, alignment

I'm cutting CSS and facing a problem, if I try to change the line-height, padding, margin of any of the last 2 items of the menu, other items will be affected. Here is the screenshot of my current menu:

[image: current menu layout]

And this is what I wish my menu to look like.

[image: target menu layout]

You can have a look at the code I wrote on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atn_php_2014/SZGXL/5/).

How can I make the icons align properly, and easy to adjust?

Comment: Remove the `overflow:hidden;` property from the menu and adjust the *other* menu items to align to the bottom of the `li`.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to achieve what you're after.

First off though, your code was very messy and in future you should prune/clean it before asking others to help you fix it. I took a 15 minute look at your code to understand it, and then rewrote the parts you're asking about with much less mess. This is what I get with the structure I've prepared for you:

[image]

The main problem with your original structure is that you were implementing the images as background images, which are harder to control, and not so good for your purpose.

I put the images directly into the HTML instead, and controlled their position and size through CSS. On that note, you can't place an `<img>` tag inside an `<li>`, so I made the icon elements within the top level list `<ul>`'s instead, they are lists anyway, aren't they?

I put the 'EN' over the earth icon, I really think it looks a lot better, because everything aligns much more consistently than your original target - but of course it's up to you.

I used the `display:table-cell;` property on all of the navigation links for it's many great features. It allows better control over spacing and centering content.

Lastly, I restructured the HTML and renamed classes to make it far easier to see what's going on.

Everything is now sitting comfortably in a good position, and responds very well to changing the window size.

#### Check out [your new navigation JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/domwebdev/P8esv/2/), it's been on a strict diet, and now it's easy to see what's going on, and much easier to adjust and improve.

Just for flips and wiggles, I decided to make it even better:

[image]

#### Check out [the even better version here](http://jsfiddle.net/domwebdev/P8esv/6/).

Answer (score 0):

**If you can change the HTML/markup:** just add a class to those two particular elements and style that.

**If you can't:**
Use `nth-child` or preferably `nth-last-child(n)`. The latter will count backwards from the last child-element instead of forwards from the first.

The code below would select the last two `li` elements in a `ul` container with the class `main-nav` applied. The `>` ensures that we only target direct children and not potential sub-menus as well:

```
ul.main-nav > li:nth-last-child(1) {
    // your style  
}

ul.main-nav > li:nth-last-child(2) {
    // your style  
}
```

Source:
http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

If you need to support older browsers (prior to IE 8) you will want to look into the relevant section in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) as well.